# Analysis: uniform convergence of a series

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, uniform-convergence

Question: Suppose $(a_k)$ and $(b_k)$ are sequences of bounded functions defined on a set *S*. a is defined and bounded on *S*, and $a_k\to a$ uniformly on S.

Suppose that the functions $b_k\ge 0$ for all k, and $\sum b_k$ converges uniformly on *S*. Prove that $\sum a_k b_k$ also converges uniformly on *S*.

That's the second part of the whole question. I have done the first part, showing that there exists a number *M* such that $|a_k (x)|\le M$ for all *k* and all *x* $\in S$. But I have no idea how it is related to the second part.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I just mix up the variables. I have amended that. Thanks.

Comment: Note that if $\epsilon$ ever arises when estimating things involving $\sum b_k$, then $\epsilon \cdot M$ might be worth looking at to estimate things involving $\sum a_k b_k$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a version of Weiersrass's "M-test" that solves your problem, that you can find as [exercise 9.3.25 at page 383](https://books.google.ro/books?id=vA9d57GxCKgC&pg=PA383) of "Elementary Real Analysis" by Thomson, Bruckner & Bruckner (2nd edition, 2008). It says that

> if $(f_k)_k$ and $(g_k)_k$ are sequences of functions such that $| f_k | \le g_k \ \forall k$, and if $\sum g_k$ converges uniformly, then $\sum f_k$ converges uniformly.

Choose $f_k = a_k b_k$ and $g_k = M b_k$ (where $M$ was obtained in the first part of the question) and you are done.